# How to hide dash between the bars in waterfall charts of Highcharts in iOS

Tags: swift, highcharts

Basically I want to hide dash between the bars from waterfall chart.I am using highcharts iOS wrapper.I can only change type of dash but there is no option to hide or disable the same

[image: Actual Waterfall chart[1]]
  [image: Expected Output]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Whenever you ask any question you need to share your effort what have you done so far and the problem which you're facing. Sharing the expected result will be more helpful to understand the requirement.

Comment: Are you able to change the dash colour? If so set the colour same as the background colour to make it hide.

Comment: No. There is no option to change the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `lineWidth` property to `0`:

```
let plotOptions = HIPlotOptions()
plotOptions.waterfall = HIWaterfall()
plotOptions.waterfall.lineWidth = 0
options.plotOptions = plotOptions
```

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/

Comment: I managed to hide those lines by making series.linecolor as white.But yours is the best solution.Thank You.Will implement this way.